# How to delete a file named NUL on an ASP.NET server

Tags: asp.net, nul

Let's start by saying that I have an account on a ASP.NET hosting company.
And about 2 weeks ago I got a malicious files uploaded to my website, and it has this name 'nul.doc.asp'.

I tried to delete it and I couldn't because it's named NUL.

I searched and found that if I use `\\.` or `\\?` before the root directory then I can delete it, but it didn't work.

I use FileZilla to send the commands to the server.

I tried

```
DELE \\./petrasurprise.com/wwwroot/images/nul.doc.asp
```

but it said 'invalid file name'

I tried also

```
DELE \\?/petrasurprise.com/wwwroot/images/nul.doc.asp
```

still the same result.

So can someone please write me down the command that can help me get rid of this malicious file?

I contacted the Customer Support and they are sleeping and useless.

Comment: Try `DELE /images/nul.doc.asp`. You probably don't have access to `/petrasurprise.com` so your root folder is the `wwwroot`. But why not just browse to the folders with FileZlla and delete the file instead of sending commands?

Comment: No I have access to /petrasurprise.com , normally browsing and deleting the file won't do anything because you can't delete a file named 'NUL' in Windows or a Windows Server in that matter, I tried to use the successful way to delete the file name 'NULL' on windows by adding '\\?' or '\\.' before the root, but it didn't work.

Comment: Check this http://superuser.com/questions/282194/how-do-i-remove-a-file-named-nul-on-windows. But this probably only works when you are logged in as Admin on the server, not with FTP.

Comment: Yeah that's my problem I don't have administrator access on the server, I only got an ftp account on a shared server.
And the useless Admin on the Customer Support has taken 2 weeks on 1 line of code.